# How to make it so that the bot creates a text channel, with the command user and a certain role with access to the channel? (Rewrite)

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a server and I want private tickets. How do you make it so that the role "Support" and the command user are the only ones to access the channel?(Bots can too).

Current code:

```py
@client.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    global ticketNumber
    ticketNumber = str(ticketNumber)
    name = 'Tickets'
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-{ticketNumber}', category=category)
    ticketNumber = int(ticketNumber) + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Text Channel with Permissions you can add the parameter `overwrites={}`. 
It takes a **Dictonary** of the targets so you have to get the "Support" role with the `utils.get()` function:

---

```python
support_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Support")

overwrites = {
   ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
   ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
   support_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
   ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
}

await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-{ticketNumber}', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
```

---

The dictonary `overwrites` takes a Member or Role. In this example:

1. `ctx.guild.default_role` for @everyone
2. `ctx.guild.me` for the bot itself
3. `support_role` for the support role
4. `ctx.author` for the command user